# crash in the load of android application

Tags: android

I get a crash in the load phase of my application.
here after the source code:

**DiscoveryMain.java**

```
package com.heeere.androiddnssd.discovery;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class DiscoveryMain extends Activity {



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                    startActivity(browserIntent);
                }
            });


    }    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:scrollbars="vertical"
              android:fadeScrollbars="true"
              android:isScrollContainer="true">
    <TextView  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Hello World, Android Discovery" />
    <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello, I am a TextView" />
    <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello, I am a Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.heeere.androiddnssd.discovery">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>

    <application>
         <activity android:name=".MainTest" android:label="DiscoveryActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**LogCat**

```
09-11 11:21:18.186: W/dalvikvm(3415): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e170)
09-11 11:21:18.196: E/AndroidRuntime(3415): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
09-11 11:21:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(3415): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.heeere.androiddnssd.discovery/com.heeere.androiddnssd.discovery.MainTest}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.heeere.androiddnssd.discovery.MainTest in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44798cd0
09-11 11:21:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(3415):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
09-11 11:21:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(3415):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
09-11 11:21:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(3415):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
09-11 11:21:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(3415):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
09-11 11:21:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(3415):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-11 11:21:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(3415):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-11 11:21:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(3415):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
09-11 11:21:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(3415):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-11 11:21:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(3415):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-11 11:21:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(3415):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-11 11:21:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(3415):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-11 11:21:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(3415):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-11 11:21:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(3415): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.heeere.androiddnssd.discovery.MainTest in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44798cd0
09-11 11:21:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(3415):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
09-11 11:21:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(3415):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
09-11 11:21:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(3415):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
09-11 11:21:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(3415):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
09-11 11:21:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(3415):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
09-11 11:21:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(3415):     ... 11 more
```

what is the proble in my code ?

Comment: will you please add your log on the crash

Comment: we would be more helpful if you post the logcat

Comment: can you please paste Manifest file.

Comment: Hello. this Code Is Complete Run In my computer.i thing other minor problem in Manifest file.please check it.thanks

Comment: your start activity is `android:name=".MainTest"` in manifest but this activity is `DiscoveryMain`. please fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you have this in your manifest?

```
  <activity
            android:name=".DiscoveryMain"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**update:**

What is your start Activity? DiscoveryMain or MainTest? please add the correct one

Comment: the manifest file is attached also. and it doesn't contain intent-filter

Comment: what is your start Activity? DiscoveryMain or MainTest?

Answer (score 2):

Please Use below..

```
<application>
     <activity android:name=".DiscoveryMain">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem. inspired from ***breceivemail***
in the Manifest file Just use

```
<activity android:name=".DiscoveryMain" android:label="DiscoveryActivity">
```

instead of

```
<activity android:name=".MainTest" android:label="DiscoveryActivity">
```